Print values from one list not contained in another
I want to check whether the elements in two arrays are different using Python.
I don't want to use numpy and sticking with general Python.
Here is an example below:
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

I expect the output to be [8,9,10]
So far I've tried to carry out a for loop
for x in range(len(arr1)):
    for y in range(len(arr2)):
        if arr1[x] != arr2[y]:
            print(arr2[y])

But, I receive this as output from print statement - 2345678910134567891012456789101235678910123467891012345789101234568910

You're probably looking for set difference.

@AndrewYim Not if duplicates are to be preserved

@Pepwave If you have lists [1, 1] and [1], should the output be [], or [1]?

Why is arr1 a prefix of arr2? Is that always the case, or is that just a terrible example?

With python one-liner:
res = [x for x in array2 if x not in array1]
print(res) # Output : [8, 9, 10]

Equivalent method for conventional iteration
lst = []
for x in array2:
    if x not in array1:
        lst.append(x)
print(lst) # Output : [8, 9, 10]


Thanks bud. This answers my question.

Your code is comparing every element in the first array to every element in the second array, and will print the element every time the two elements don't match.
Instead, you need to compare every element in the first array to all elements in the second array, and only print the element if there is no match.
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for num in arr2:
    if num not in arr1:
        print(num)

I would note that this implementation is not very efficient. In many cases, it makes sense to compare sets:
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
output = list(set(arr2) - set(arr1))
print(output) 


Note - Comparing sets would remove duplicates.

You can get some performance benefits in the first style of code if you change one of the lists to be a set instead. Using value in some_set is O(1) on average, rather than O(N) to search through a list.

You could you use the set() to find only the unique entries and subtract both the sets and convert the answer to a list using the list() func.
arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

arr1.sort()
arr2.sort()

if arr1 == arr2:
    print("The arrays are equal.")
else:
    arr3=list(set(arr2) - set(arr1))
    print(arr3)

